# Want to develop android game

Tags: android

I want to develop a 3D multiplayer game for android , what is the best game engine , what is the best software to create 3d objects to import them to android ?

Thank you .

Comment: 'Best' is very subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204363/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-3d-model-into-android) question explains how to load models into android.

A quick google search for Android 3D Engines gave me:

[jPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/)

[Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) now does Android - this is a great option, but I believe you have to pay. It probably is the 'best' engine by any means..except cost.

Comment: besides those 2 you can also try shiva3D you need commertial lisence for this one also but it's a little cheaper